# Promise, .then() variable keeps saying undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor

I'm having issues with variable scope. The code below is in Protractor which is a mix of Jasmine and JavaScript. The issue that I'm having is that I'm trying to use string value from `householdLabelText` and compare it to the value of `householdArray[i]`.

However, whenever I do this, `householdArray[i]` comes back as undefined. I'm guessing this is because `householdArray` goes out of scope or something. I'm not exactly an expert how the Promise/callback thing works, so I may be wrong. If anyone could give me some tips on how to keep `householdArray` in scope, I would appreciate it.

```
it((testNumber += 1) + '---' + suiteName + '---' +
'It should dispaly the appropraite text for the rating factors.',
    function() {

        var householdArray = ['ACCIDENTS', 'VIOLATIONS', 'DRIVERS', 'VEHICLES', 'TENURE'];

        element.all(by.repeater('item in vm.policyDetails.householdDetails')).then(function(householdDetails) {

            for(var i = 0; i < householdDetails.length; i++)
            {
                householdDetails[i].element(by.binding('item.label')).getText().then(function(householdLabelText) {
                console.log(householdArray[i]);
                expect(householdLabelText).toEqual(householdArray[i]); // householdArray[i] is undefined
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you need to learn how to use the step debugger,  the step debugger is your friend!

Comment: Can you post an example ([codepen](codepen.io)) of your code that produces the problem?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I don't have an IDE or a way to use a step debugger. If you can recommend me a step debugger for Protractor, then I'll use it.

Comment: @threed I added a console.log() where it would print undefined.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I'm guessing he's not very familiar with step debuggers, since he didn't realize they were baked into browsers, which I think indicates that he's just uncertain, not lazy.

Comment: *[codepen](http://codepen.io/)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Protractor is not a like a typical language. I don't know of any IDE's to use with it. And a step debugger in the browser doesn't work. When running a test, if you open the debugger it closes the test immediately.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson would you also like to link me to the duplicate?

Comment: @DrZoo The duplicate is now showing up at the top of your question.

Comment: @threed I disagree at the duplicate, but whatever.

Comment: I didn't choose the duplicate, but it does seem possible that it's closely related. Without a running example of your code, it's difficult to help much further. Please consider creating a CodePen that produces the same issue.

Comment: Use array.forEach(function(Value,index,arr){}) method instead of for loop in your code. It will perfectly work

Comment: @SureshSalloju I'll give it a shot when I get back to work tomorrow.

Comment: @SureshSalloju that worked. Thanks! You can move it to an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: @DrZoo  cool.Nope yaar

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `householdArray` is fine since it has been declared in the test function block and you are using it in a nested function so it should absolutely be in scope.

What is a more likely cause is that the value of `i` causes it to read beyond the array bounds because `householdDetails.length` might be different than `householdArray.length`. That's the first thing I would check in this instance.